# Why is ((v k)^-n (k v^n - v k^n))/(n - 1) == b so hard for Mathematica to solve (for v)?

Tags: equation-solving

I've tried using both `Solve` and `Reduce`.  For something that takes maybe 3 minutes to solve with paper and pencil, I'm very surprised and disappointed.

Am I doing something inherently wrong?  Making a stupid mistake?  Is there some other function I should be using?  Sorry if you've seen this one before.

```
Solve[((v k)^-n (k v^n - v k^n))/(n - 1) == b, v]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: What are you solving for? Also, make sure you have specified Assumptions for all the parameters.

Comment: Thanks to Karsten for restoring my original question.  Solving for v.  Only assumption used is n!=1.

Comment: And everything Real perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It requires a transformation that is not generically valid. Also it is a bit hard to make it happen using `Simplify` due to the default complexity measure.

```
Solve[
 Simplify[((v k)^-n (k v^n - v k^n))/(n - 1) == b, 
  Assumptions -> k > 0, 
  ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 
      5*Count[#, Power[aa_, Except[_Integer]], Infinity] &)], v]

During evaluation of In[181]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

(* Out[181]= {{v -> ((-b - k^(1 - n)/(1 - n)) (-1 + n))^(1/(1 - n))}} *)
```

Instead of `Simplify` one might use `PowerExpand with appropriate assumption.

```
Solve[
 PowerExpand[((v k)^-n (k v^n - v k^n))/(n - 1) == b, 
  Assumptions -> k > 0], v]

During evaluation of In[182]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

(* Out[182]= {{v -> ((-b - k^(1 - n)/(1 - n)) (-1 + n))^(1/(1 - n))}} *)
```